# Need to refactor a node.js app to be used on a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

```
const episodes = [
  { id: 's06e01', title: 'Pilot' },
  { id: 's06e02', title: 'Top Banana' },
  { id: 's06e03', title: 'Charity Drive' },
  { id: 's06e04', title: 'Visiting Ours' },
  { id: 's06e05', title: 'My Mother, the Car' },
  { id: 's06e06', title: 'In God We Trust' },
  { id: 's06e07', title: 'Storming the castle' },
  { id: 's06e08', title: 'Pier Pressure' },
  { id: 's06e09', title: 'Public Relations' },
];

const finaleEpisode = { id: 's06e10', title: 'Bringing Up Buster' };

const addToPlaylist = episodes.concat(finaleEpisode)

for (let i = 0; i < addToPlaylist.length; i++) {



   setTimeout(() => {
        // clears all characters printer on previous loop
        process.stdout.clearLine();

        // use \r at the end to return the cursor to the begining 
        process.stdout.write("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[i].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[i].title + "\r");
    }, i * 2000);
}

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\x1Bc'); }, 21000);
```

when this code is run on Node.js the console log displays each episode one at a time then gets removed to display the next episode, delayed by one second on each iteration and concatenated with the string "you are now watching"

I would like to reformat the code to first displays the entire object on the browser, then once it is displayed I need it remove the episodes in chronological order from the browser until the browser is not displaying anything, and also to utilize .filter() and Object.assign() to the reformatted code.

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck? StackOverflow isn't for doing your work, it's for helping with very specific problems where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you please ask a specific question?

Comment: Throw out `process` calls, replace `process..write` with `console.log`.

Comment: If you just want to "convert" your nodejs programm to browser friendly JS, have a look at [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: It is not clear what you're really asking for help with.  It sounds like you need to first start writing some new code that could display things in a browser and then ask a more specific question about where you get stuck when doing that.  You can't direct port code that uses `process.stdout` from node.js.  That doesn't exist in the browser and you display things in a browser in a completely different manner.  You would start with an HTML display and then use Javascript to modify the DOM to change it.  Pretty much completely different code.  Not a port at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you want. You will probably need to adjust the interval time (Not the 200 I have below).

```js
const episodes = [
  { id: 's06e01', title: 'Pilot' },
  { id: 's06e02', title: 'Top Banana' },
  { id: 's06e03', title: 'Charity Drive' },
  { id: 's06e04', title: 'Visiting Ours' },
  { id: 's06e05', title: 'My Mother, the Car' },
  { id: 's06e06', title: 'In God We Trust' },
  { id: 's06e07', title: 'Storming the castle' },
  { id: 's06e08', title: 'Pier Pressure' },
  { id: 's06e09', title: 'Public Relations' },
  { id: 's06e10', title: 'Bringing Up Buster' }
];

var i = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('output');

var interval = setInterval(
  () => {
    if (i >= episodes.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      el.textContent = 'You are finished watching everything';
      return;
    }

    el.textContent = `You are Now Watching ${episodes[i].id} ${episodes[i].title}`;
    i++;
  }, 200);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```